# Flutter - Error -32601 received from application: Method not found

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, emulation

My app builds normally on the emulator, but then the screen goes blank and I get this on the terminal:

"Error -32601 received from the application: Method not found".

The dependencies are updated.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add:

import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as tm;

Also, add this on your 'void main()', on main.dart:

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();